# Getting last element of a nested list in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I got a list in my template which is something like :

`[[('a', 'b', 'c')], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]` (but the list length is not always the same)

I want to access 2 elements from this list:

- The first element of the first sublist (here it's `'a'`). Easy : `{{ the_list.0.0 }}`
- The first element of the last sublist (here it's `'g'`). How to do this?

I tried `{{ the_list|last.0 }}`but it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dit it with a custom tag.
If there is not another way, I'll mark this as right answer.

```
@register.filter
def first_of_last_sublist(input_list):
    try:
        return input_list[-1][0]
    except:
        return input_list
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
{% with last_element=the_list|last %}
    {{ last_element.0 }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Ahh, Smart, didn't think of that :) As I am actually already using a `with`tag for another reason in the same code, I guess it's better in my case to use custom tag (see my answer) rather than nesting `with`tags, right?

Comment: It depends on which solution makes your code cleaner and easier to understand. Personally I'd stick with {% with %} statement, it's a one templatetag less to maintain :)

Answer (score -1):

`{{ the_list|last }}` will give you `['g' , 'h', 'i']`.

So try `{{ {{ the_list|last }}.0 }}`

Comment: You can't use templates like this. You need to create a temp variable with `{% with %}`.